# What are the differences between two different EWMA estimator?

Tags: time-series, exponential-smoothing, unevenly-spaced-time-series

Someone just showed me a different way of recursively estimating EWMA based on the exponential sum.  The estimator has two different recursions: one for the sum and another for the weight.
$$
\alpha=e^{-\frac{\Delta t}{\tau}}
$$
$$
s_t=x_t+\alpha\cdot s_{t-1}
$$
$$
w_t=1+\alpha\cdot w_{t-1}
$$
$$
ewma_t=\frac{s_t}{w_t}
$$I've always used a more standard definition:
$$
ewma_t=(1-\alpha)\cdot x_t+\alpha\cdot ewma_{t-1}
$$
The claims was that for irregular time series, where $\Delta t$ could become very small this new estimation technique performs better.  I could see that if we get 2 observations with exactly the same timestamp ($\Delta t=0$), the standard definition will "ignore" one.  However, his version will estimate the average between the two.  I've never seen $ewma$ defined that way and I can't find any references for it.  I just want to get some opinions in what situations it should be used and what are the advantages / disadvantages?